# Visual Debugger document outline keeps collapsing

Tags: xcode, debugging

Each time I run my app and enter the visual debugger, the view hierarchy starting with the window is collapsed.  It then takes 10-20 seconds for me to unfold the tree and locate the view I'm interested in.  **Sometimes**, it retains the unfolded tree between runs.  But most of the time it collapses fully.  Is there something I can do so that visual debugging state is preserved?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about remembering it, but if you hold option key while opening it, it will expand the whole tree, simplifying the process a bit. Alternatively, I find that clicking on it (to select it) and then using the right and up/down keyboard keys to be a faster way to selectively expand the tree.

Comment: You can also right click on the view in question, choose "focus", and then when you exit "focus mode", you'll see your UI tree expanded to the view in question